# Django Forms - Is 'readonly' safe to use?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I created a form in Django. In this form, there is a field that must not be edited by the user, because the default value of the form must be sent to my database as it is. I come up with the following solution, but after making some research, i've come to find that using `readOnly` is generally not a good idea.

Can someone clarify me on this? Should i go with another solution?

```
tst = forms.CharField(
        initial='//value to be sent to the db without being touched',

        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
```

Comment: All validation that has to be safe should be done in the model (and maybe in the form again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**: since this is only an attribute at the *client* side. But a user could simply bypass that. For example by making a POST request without the browser, or by altering the `readonly` attribute by manipulating the DOM.

Since [django-1.9](/questions/tagged/django-1.9), you can use the [**`disabled=...`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) parameter. This will not only make the HTML element disabled, but it will also omit GET/POST parameters with that name, as is described by the documentation:

> The `disabled` boolean argument, when set to `True`, **disables a form field using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by users**. Even **if a user tampers with the field’s value** submitted to the server, it will be **ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data**.

So you could implement your form with:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tst = forms.CharField(
        initial='//value to be sent to the db without being touched',
        disabled=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput)
    )
```

Note that if you only plan to assign a value, you should omit that field from the form, and just assign it in the model.

Comment: Yes, assigning it on the module would be the perfect solution. The problem is that i have to use the same form two times in the same page. All the fields will be in common except one, this is why i set it to disabled. The first form will have a X disabled field, the second one will have a Y disabled field

Comment: @Jack002: well evidently it depends on the use case. Here it probably is indeed better to use a form.

Comment: So, basically using disabled will be the safest way to go? I'm asking because security is an important feature for the project i'm working on

Comment: @Jack022: the documentation says: "*The disabled boolean argument, when set to True, disables a form field using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data.*". So given there are no bugs in Django, this should indeed be the case. Evidently there are bugs in Django (but perhaps not for this feature). So you can never "fully" trust this, but it is at least the intended behavior.